# DbContextFactory InvalidOperationException in Blazor App

Tags: blazor-server-side, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

I’ve changed my use of DbContext to incorporating DbContextFactory in order to handle multiple sql transactions. I’ve run into a couple questions/errors trying to do this.

1. I have 3 different tables in my database that are accessed for different functions so I created 3 different services to handle them. Is this correct? Is there a better way? I'm not sure this if this is related to the problem but I want to make sure I'm not adding unnecessary complications.

   My tables: Category, Expense, Items
   My services: CategoryService, ExpenseService, ItemService
   Each service has a GetAll, GetbyKey, Update, and Delete.
2. After adding the DbContextFactory to my services, I’m getting an error I don’t understand.
   Here’s part of my Program.cs code:

> ```
> builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
> builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
> builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<BudgetDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection")); 
> builder.Services.AddScoped<ExpenseService>();
> builder.Services.AddScoped<CategoryService>();
> builder.Services.AddScoped<ItemService>();
> builder.Services.AddDbContext<BudgetDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
> var app = builder.Build();
> ```

Here’s the part of my page code:

```
    private async void GetCategories()
{
    categories = await categoryService.GetAllCategories();
    GetUICategories(categories, uiCategories, uiSubCategories);
}
```

Here’s the part of my CategoryService code:

```
        public async Task<List<Category>> GetAllCategories()
    {
        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        return await dbContext.Categories.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Here’s the error that’s happening at `return await dbContext.Categories.ToListAsync();` in the CategoryService:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Instance failure.'

I think I must have added the DbContextFactory incorrectly in the Progam file but I'm not sure that's what the problem is.

**Update**: I meant to post the following for the AddDbContextFactory line.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<BudgetDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=DESKTOP-JMIKVDI\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BudgetDB;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"));
```

Using DefaultConnection as AddDbContext does changes the error.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<BudgetDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling both `AddDbContextFactory`  `AddDbContext`, lose ``AddDbContext`.`  Second this `private async void GetCategories()` should be `private async Task GetCategories()`.  However, I don't think either will fix your problem.  You need to use something like `XUnit` to write a simple test that just tests the EF connection.  Search  "c# XUnit test ef".  here's a nice article - https://www.carlrippon.com/testing-ef-core-repositories-with-xunit-and-an-in-memory-db/.

Comment: On your more general question, There's an article of mine here that will give you some ideas and pointers - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5350000/A-Different-Repository-Pattern-Implementation.  It also shows how to using XUnit testing to test your data pipeline.

Comment: Thank you! This will take me a minute to figure out but it looks like the right direction.